# Option for user to add input to power BI dashboard

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a simple power BI dashboard. It contains a table like below

| Customer Name | Product | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | Widget | 10.99 | 2 |
| Jane Doe | Gizmo | 5.99 | 3 |
| Bob Johnson | Doodad | 8.49 | 1 |

What i want is to enable a sales rep to accept or reject a price and if he/she rejects a price, there should be an option to enter a new price which he/she thinks is correct.
How do I do that? Is it possible to do in power BI? chatgpt says to use something like a form which i could not find in the visuals.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with Power Apps to do that: [Power Apps visual for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual)